# How to check if a certain part of the array exists in another array?

Tags: php, arrays, intersection

I have an two associative arrayes and I want to check if

```
$array1["foo"]["bar"]["baz"] exists in $array2["foo"]["bar"]["baz"]
```

The values doesn't matter, just the "path".
Does [array_ intersect_ assoc](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) do what I need?
If not how can I write one myself?

Comment: How do you know that you are looking for the path ["foo"]["bar"]["baz"]? Where do you get the information from?

Comment: I get the input from the URI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
function array_path_exists(&$array, $path, $separator = '/')
{
    $a =& $array;
    $paths = explode($separator, $path);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($paths as $p) {
        if (isset($a[$p])) {
            if ($i == count($paths) - 1) {
                return TRUE;
            }
            elseif(is_array($a[$p])) {
                $a =& $a[$p];
            }
            else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

// Test
$test = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => array(
            'baz' => 1
            )
        ),
    'bar' => 1
    );

echo array_path_exists($test, 'foo/bar/baz');

?>
```

Comment: I will test it tomorrow.
If it works can I credit you in my code?

Comment: A link to this question will do-- spread the word! (Assuming it does what you want...)

Comment: works with a minor change:
I am using this preg_match_all('([\w.-]+)', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $paths); instead of explode as it doesn't fit the array I need.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to check if the keys exist you could use a simple if statement.

```
<?php
if (isset($array1["foo"]["bar"]["baz"]) && isset($array2["foo"]["bar"]["baz"]
```

)) {
        //exists
    }

Comment: That works if I know the depth that I need to check.
It's can also be array1["baz"]["bar"] exists in array2["baz"]["bar"] if there is a different input.